# What 意思 means in below?

Tags: translation

In this situation, B gave A (B's leader) some bonus money.

- A：“你这是什么意思？” 　　'what do you mean?'
- B：“没什么意思，意思意思。”'nothing. just .?.'
- A：“你这人真有意思。” 　　  ?
- B：“其实也没有别的意思。” 　?
- A：“那我就不好意思了。” 　　?
- B：“是我不好意思。”        ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A: What do you mean? *or* What do you intend to?
>
> B: Nothing, just a little bit of thank you gift.
>
> A: You are bit of an interesting guy.
>
> B: Do not take it seriously, I have no favour to ask for.
>
> A: Alright, I might better keep this.
>
> B: It is my pleasure.

In Chinese, those words could actually mean

> 甲：你这（给我钱）是什么意思？
>
> 乙：没什么意思，就是表示一下（感谢）。
>
> 甲：你这人还挺懂事的。
>
> 乙：我真的没别的意思，还望您笑纳。
>
> 甲：那我就腆着脸收下了。
>
> 乙：嗨，这是我应该的。

Comment: @KacieChen It means 厚着脸皮，thus there is no ambiguity in the sentence.

Comment: @KacieChen I improved my answer a little bit, especially on the last that B said.

Answer (score 2):

意 = intention

思 = thought

意思: thought; meaning; intention

> A：“你这是什么(意思)？” --  "What is the (meaning/ intention) of this?"
>
> B：“没什么(意思)，[意思意思]。”  --  "No (meaning) whatsoever,  just my [little expression]

***意思意思*** literally means "**thought, thought**". The full meaning of this phrase is "just a small token that **express** my **thought and feeling**"

> A：“你这人真**有意思**。” 　--  "You are really **interesting**"

***有意思*** literally means "**have meaning**" . Logically, people only interesting in something meaningful, therefore, 有意思  (have meaning) also means "interesting/ meaningful" in Chinese

> B：“其实也没有别的(意思)。” 　really  have no other (meaning/ intention)
>
> A：“那我就(不好意思)了。” 　Then I would go ahead and (feel embarrassed)
>
> *Meaning: Then I would go ahead and make myself feel embarrassed for taking the money*
>
> B：“是我(不好意思)。” --  "It is I who should (feel embarrassed)"
>
> *Meaning: I am the one who should feel embarrassed for offering so little, not you who rightfully taking the money*

***不好意思*** literally means: 不好 (**not easy to**) 意思 (**thought**) . The full meaning of "不好意思" is  "not easy to express this thought" -- Having embarrassing thought is difficult to express,

*In short, "不好意思" means "feel embarrassed" or "sorry" * ; "好意思" means "not feel embarrassed" or "not sorry"

*Example:*

*你還(**好意思**)説 = Yet, you (**don't feel embarrassed**) to say*

*我(**不好意思**)説 = I (**feel embarrassed**) to say*

**Summary:**

意思: thought; meaning; intention

有意思: meaningful; interesting

意思意思: just a little expression (of thought/ feeling)

不好意思: feel embarrassed/ sorry

好意思: not feel embarrassed/ not sorry

**Side note:**

*意思意思 in Cantonese is 小小心意 (literally means "little thought")*